# Java mongodriver 3.4.9 what is the easiest way to use $inc and $sum operators to update a field

Tags: java, mongodb

i'm using mongodb for my java application and i'm stuck in this problem, i want to convert mongo operations in java language but i can't find the solution. Mongo operations are:

$inc:

```
db.products.update(
   { _id: "someId" },
   { $inc: { quantity: +2 } }
)
```

$sum:

```
db.students.aggregate([
   {
     $group: {
       value: { $sum: valueToAdd},
     }
   }
])
```

This is what i ended up so far but still not working.

```
Bson filter = Filters.eq("_id", someId);
UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);   
Bson incrementFirstTry = new Document("$inc", new Document().append("quantity", 2));
Bson incrementSecondTry = new Document("quantity", +2);
Bson sumFirstTry = new Document("$sum", new Document("value", valueToAdd))
Bson sumSecondTry = Aggregates.group(someId, Accumulators.sum("value", valueToAdd));

collection.updateOne(filter, incrementFirstTry, options);
collection.updateOne(filter, incrementSecondTry, options);
collection.updateOne(filter, sumFirstTry, options);
collection.updateOne(filter, sumSecondTry, options);
```

both when incrementing it says that quantity is a string so it cannot be added to an integer.

when using $sum it either says: com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Unknown modifier: $group OR com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Unknown modifier: $sum

i know what i've tried is not quite correct but i don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. If I had to guess, I'd say that the `quantity` field in your `products` table somehow got a string into the quantity field.  `incrementFirstTry` looks good; `incrementSecondTry` is not doing what you think; it is just setting the field to positive 2, not incrementing it by 2.
2. You are missing the `_id` field in the `$group` statement.

Comment: $inc operation worked fine, i found a misplaced curly brackets in my code... Still trying to make the $sum operation work. I have no more error thanks for your advice though, thanks.